# How to put powershell commands in an array?

Tags: arrays, multithreading, powershell, imagemagick-convert, start-job

I have a script that does a bunch of image processing. So far it runs sequentially, uses only one core and takes forever. I have four cores at hand. I want to run four of these commands at the same time. To make this happen, I need to put the commands in an array. These are the original commands:

```
convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 1  C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_1_21_Northland.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg
convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 22 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_22_31_Auckland.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg
convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 32 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_32_49_Waikato.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg
convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 50 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_50_62_Whanganui.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg
convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 63 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_63_69_Manawatu.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg
convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 70 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_70_75_Wellington.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg
convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 76 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_76_92_Marlborough.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg
convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 93 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_93_117_Canterbury.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg
convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 118 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_118_127_Otago.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg
convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 128 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_128_141_Southland.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg
```

So far I came up with this:

```
$array = @()
$array += "convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 1  C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_1_21_Northland.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d_test.jpg"
$array += "convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 22 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_22_31_Auckland.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d_test.jpg"
$array += "convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 32 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_32_49_Waikato.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg"
$array += "convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 50 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_50_62_Whanganui.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg"
$array += "convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 63 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_63_69_Manawatu.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg"
$array += "convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 70 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_70_75_Wellington.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg"
$array += "convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 76 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_76_92_Marlborough.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg"
$array += "convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 93 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_93_117_Canterbury.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg"
$array += "convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 118 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_118_127_Otago.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg"
$array += "convert.exe -density 200 -quality 80 -delete 0 -scene 128 C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\v33_128_141_Southland.pdf C:\Users\mles\Desktop\ta2014\%03d.jpg"

foreach ($element in $array) {
   $MaxThreads = 4
   While (@(Get-Job | Where { $_.State -eq "Running" }).Count -ge $MaxThreads)
   {  Write-Host "Waiting for open thread...($MaxThreads Maximum)"
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
   }

   Start-Job -Scriptblock{ $element }
}

While (@(Get-Job | Where { $_.State -eq "Running" }).Count -ne 0)
{  Write-Host "Waiting for background jobs..."
   Get-Job    #Just showing all the jobs
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

ForEach ($Job in (Get-Job)) {
   Remove-Job $Job
}
```

The jobs start but quit immediately. I guess it has to do with how I'm storing the commands in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj148984(v=vs.85).aspx) but they bump up against a max of 5 concurrent processes. There are also several examples of using runspace pools and powershell to implement multi threading in a manner that bypasses this limit. I gave a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332039/can-pipelines-run-concurrently-in-the-same-runspace).

Alternatively just store the scriptblocks as scriptblocks in the array instead of as strings.

```
$commands = @()
$commands += {echo "test1"}
$commands += {echo "test2"}
$commands += {echo "test3"}
foreach($command in $commands){
    start-job $command
}
```

Comment: I stumbled upon workflows and runspace pools, but I have to admit using jobs is the only example I kinda understood. My script is based on this example: http://thesurlyadmin.com/2013/03/04/multithreading-revisited-using-jobs/ . I only need 4 concurrent processes, as I only have 4 cores.

Comment: Edited to show how to use scriptblocks in the array as this seems to be more what you are looking for.